# Likert Package - Plot Percents

Tags: r

I'm re-posting this as I didn't provide enough information the first time and I thik it's been buried as a result. I've update the original post here:

[Plot Percents with Likert Package - Doesn`t work when grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057697/plot-percents-with-likert-package-doesnt-work-when-grouping)

Hopefully someone can help me solve this.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not a valid reason to post a new question.

Comment: If you don't think you provided enough information **edit** the question. This will also bump the question to the home page (however briefly) and get it more attention.