# Re-ordering Factor Levels with Likert Package - R

Tags: r, plot

Using this page as a reference http://jason.bryer.org/likert/ I am finding that when I replicate Bryers code with my own data the likert factor levels are in the wrong order. This doesn't seem to happen with the demo code but does with mine.

I plot with

```
plot(lexam, centered = FALSE, wrap = 30)
```

to get the image you see

I tried to amend with the following without success.

```
levels <- c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neutral", "Disagree","Strongly Disagree")
lexam[] <- lapply(lexam, function(x) factor(x, levels = levels))
```

Can anybody suggest what I can do to re-order the factor levels for the plot? You should see in the linked image where the problem is. [Incorrect Likert Ordering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zNaV.png)

Interestingly I've seen the same problem in other posts where it's not actually the problem being discussed. For example [Plot Percents with Likert Package - Doesn`t work when grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057697/plot-percents-with-likert-package-doesnt-work-when-grouping) you can see the same issue even though it's not the topic of discussion.

Comment: It seems that your problem is rather concerned with reordering factors in R than with the `likert` package. [The subject](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reorder+factors+%5Br%5D) of ordering factors in R is as old as this site so you could pick from one of many solutions available through SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ordered` function [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html) to create an ordered factor. See also this [tutorial](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Changing_the_order_of_levels_of_a_factor/)

```
levels <- c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neutral", "Disagree","Strongly Disagree")
ordered_factor <- ordered(x, levels = levels)
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. Stupid question but how do I then plot using the ordered factor item created?

Comment: @H.R.Badger sorry, my mistake -- you can just add it as a column to your `data.frame`, or overwrite your old column. e.g. if your `data.frame` is *lexam* and the column name *rating*, you can do `lexam['rating'] <- ordered(lexam['rating'], levels = levels)`